# How to build properly an alias?

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I put one new alias `python3.3` in my `.bash_profile` so as to launch easily the `python3.3` version of [pyzo](http://www.pyzo.org/).

I can use this alias in a terminal without any problem, but when I use something like `subprocess.check_call(args = ["python3.3", onePyFile])`, I have the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/Library/Frameworks/pyzo2013b/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/pyzo2013b/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 521, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/pyzo2013b/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 818, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/pyzo2013b/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python3.3'
```

I guess that my alias is not seen everywhere. So how can I fix my problem ? What is the good way to build my own alias ?

If I try `subprocess.check_call(args = ["python3.3", onePyFile], shell = True)`, I have the following error.

```
onePyFile.py: python3.3: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mainFile.py", line 72, in <module>
    shell = True
  File "/Library/Frameworks/pyzo2013b/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 545, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['python3.3', 'onePyFile.py']' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

If i just use `subprocess.check_call(args = ["python3.3", onePyFile])` where the first line of `onePyFile` is `#! /usr/bin/env python3.3`, I have the following error.

```
env: python3.3: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
```

I think that my problem is more about the symbolic link than the Python call. But I do not know what is wrong. Indeed this is the first time that I make a personal symbolic link with an alias.

Comment: If that is what you think, get rid of the symbolic link and use the full path to python 3.3. You may also need the full path to onePyFile.

Comment: I know I can do that but I also want to know how to fix the alias problem.

Answer (score 5):

try `subprocess.check_call(args = ["python3.3", onePyFile] , shell=True, env={'ENV':path_of_bash_profile})`

If shell is True, the specified command will be executed through the shell. This can be useful if you are using Python primarily for the enhanced control flow it offers over most system shells and still want convenient access to other shell features such as shell pipes, filename wildcards, environment variable expansion, and expansion of ~ to a user’s home directory. However, note that Python itself offers implementations of many shell-like features (in particular, glob, fnmatch, os.walk(), os.path.expandvars(), os.path.expanduser(), and shutil).

Comment: I've tried but there is still one error. I will just put it in my question.

Comment: @projetmbc  try subprocess.check_call(args = ["python3.3", onePyFile] , shell=True,env={'ENV':absolute_path_of_bash_profile})

Comment: This doesn't work. What a mess... I'm drowning... ;-)

Comment: The error is given at the end of my question that has been updated.

Answer (score 3):

That's because subprocess doesn't load a shell by default (see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call)), so it doesn't get what's in your .bash_profile.
Use this:

```
subprocess.check_call(args = ["python3.3", onePyFile], shell=True)
```

Edit: Seems like glasslion was faster than me!

Edit 2: I did a bit more digging around, and found something strange. Because shell=True didn't seem to work as expected I went with a more direct approach, calling bash directly.

a.py:

```
from subprocess import check_call
check_call(['bash', '-c', '. ~/.bash_profile && ABC a bc'])
```

a.sh (what would be your python3 executable):

```
echo $*
```

I first tried with `alias ABC='~/Documents/a.sh'` in `.bash_profile`:

```
$ python ~/Documents/a.py
bash: ABC: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Documents/a.py", line 6, in <module>
    check_call(['bash', '-c', '. ' + expanduser('~/.bash_profile') + ' && ABC a bc'])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['bash', '-c', '. ~/.bash_profile && ABC a bc']' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

Then I switched from an alias to a function: `ABC() { ~/Documents/a.sh $*; }`
And it worked!

```
$ python ~/Documents/a.py
a bc
```

Bottom line is I got it to work, but I don't know why! Shells aren't reliable, so the best would be to skip the shell.

We can do that by using the shebang's principle (as Fred Mitchell suggested) in a clever way:

```
from subprocess import check_call
check_call(['/usr/bin/env', 'python3', onePyFile])
```

This will work if Python 3 was installed correctly, independently of it's path (what I suppose you wanted to achieve).

Comment: Using a function to manage your "deployment" is very convenient. It avoids the problem of whether or not your shell profile is used and even which shell you might want. Sometimes you may find it useful to use a full path, other times a relative path. If everything is relative to a "base path", it is easy to modify, or the "base path" can be passed in at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put a shebang to python3.3 in the first line of onePyFile and omit running python explicitly?

Comment: An alternative would be to directly call `/usr/bin/env python3.3`, which skips the shebang and won't require modifying anything!

Comment: This can do the job but if I use other aliases, I will have to solve this problem.

Comment: Nothing, that's the problem. My alias only "lives" in the terminal.